# Hexadecimal representation of a binary file

Tags: java, hex, unsigned, signed, hexdump

I have a binaryfile.bin where I have a set of instructions which I have to decode to hexadecimal.
I written a program in java that does this and I get the same hexadecimal as i get from Hexdump in linux.

I know what the actual Binary should be for each of the instructions in the binary file, as this is given. Which can be seen below. I can see that there is some relation between the two hexes.

```
Hexdump  Binary                           Hex of Binary
1303d007 00000111110100000000001100010011 7D00313
93033302 00000010001100110000001110010011 2330393
138ec3f9 11111001110000111000111000010011 F9C38E13
1305a000 00000000101000000000010100010011 A00513
73000000 00000000000000000000000001110011 73
```

My question is how do I get from "hexdump" to "Hex of Binary" or How would one go about this as I am only provided with a binary file ?

I dont hope my question is too unclear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Every byte is represented by two Hex characters (each Hex is 4 bits).

Your hexdump, `1303d007` is the four bytes `13` `03` `d0` `07`.

Your hex-to-binary, `7D00313` is the same four bytes, but formatted differently and in different order. It is `07` `D0` `03` `13`. The preceding '0' on the `07` was truncated for simplicity, but then you'll notice that the order is 100% reversed.

Endianness tells you the order that bytes appear along some form of transmission or storage. It answers the question, "Is the most significant byte going to appear first or last?".

[image: Endianness comparison]